# 'Web3' is undefined in html javascript

Tags: web3js, dapps

I have geth installed and running and I am connected to a private network. As given in https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js, I have created a test html with jquery-3.1.1.min.js and web3.min.js and then my custom js code as shown below. However I am getting error: **'Web3' is undefined** in the below line. Any help please.

```
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
```

Comment: looks like there is something wrong with the inclusion of web3.min.js. Did you double check the path?

Comment: yes:     <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\a.sinha\node_modules\web3\dist\web3.min.js"></script>